# can my app knows that I received a sms on my iphone using Notification Center

Tags: iphone, nsnotificationcenter

I am, creating a app in which i need to show message to user that you received sms , is it possible using NSNotificationCenter.
Please help?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible, as far as I know. iOS treats a new SMS very similarly to a push notification sent to the system, and your code doesn't get notified of push notifications that are not sent to your app.

To reiterate, iOS does not notify your app when an SMS (text message) has been received by your phone.

Comment: can i treat it as Notifcations only i need to show message to user when received the sms

Comment: No, your app does not get the notification. Only the system does. iOS does not inform your app of SMS notifications.