# How to listen for incoming sms event in iOS

Tags: ios, notifications

Is there any example for ios that I can add observer so that I can develop an app that is aware of incoming sms/mms/email event?

Comment: Not possible, you can do that in Jailbroken devices

Comment: Is there some materials about do it on Jailbroken devices? Thanks a lot.

Comment: As I know we can't add a listener for SMS

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9100242/can-my-app-knows-that-i-received-a-sms-on-my-iphone-using-notification-center

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no public API for that in iOS but there are private API for that. If you use private API then your app will not get approved by Apple.

If you want to use private API then here is one useful solution for that. http://tech.ruimaninfo.com/?p=83

Solution is bit old so you will need to check if it works in current iOS versions. It was working in iOS 6.

Comment: The link is no more active.