# How to listen notification with cordova on iOS/Android?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, listener

I'm looking for a plugin or at least a way to listen through cordova for the incoming notifications ?

I found this plugin for android : https://github.com/coconauts/NotificationListener-cordova.

But i'm wondering if it's possible to listen for event on iOS.

At least i would like to listen for incoming call and incoming message if I can't get the notification.

Any ideas ?

Comment: i guess you have to have a look at this plugin - https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications. It the familiar plugin for notifications as far as i know and works in both iOS and Android

Comment: Yes but it's only to post local notifications, nothing to deal with incoming call or new whatsapp notification i think, i already checked this.

Answer (score 2):

As far as i have checked, there is no way to get notified on incoming message in iOS. To be more precise, there is no public API in iOS for the same. May be you have some tweaks to achieve it but eventually the app may get rejected during apple certification. The following links should provide more info on this - [Listening for sms recpetion](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/16685) & [sms reception listening](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28274728/how-to-listen-for-incoming-sms-event-in-ios)

Comment: Well, I just want to create an application for a smart device (a watch) to send a bluetooth signal on a sms receive, i don't want to read or acces it. Thanks for the link :)

Comment: @davidbonachera if the link was useful, please accept the answer so that it will be beneficial for others stuck with similar issue... Cheers..